How can I reduce the size of my Flutter app when building it in release mode using the command "flutter build apk"
How to decrease Flutter App Size
When I am building app on release mode I got app size is too large how to decrease app size anybody can explain:
runs this command:
flutter build apk
I am Expecting for reduced app size as minimum as

So what's the size of release APK now?

https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#what-is-a-fat-apk

try this command
flutter build apk --release

